# sed fails to do substitution if line is very long

Tags: mysql, sed

sed works fine on short lines but not long lines. Using the following command:

```
sed 's/DEFINER=\`[a-z]*\`@\`localhost\`//g' temp.sql
```

When temp.sql contains short lines like this it works:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`factstvdus`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `caseinfo` AS select `files`.`fileNumber` AS `fileNumber`...
```

However, with really long lines the substitution does not happen. My goal is to delete every instance of:

```
DEFINER=`factstvdus`@`localhost`
```

The username (in this case factstvdus) is not always the same. mysqldump outputs view definitions all on one long line so it's not easy to wrap them to multiple lines that I know of.

How can I get sed to process long lines or is there another tool I should use?

Update: This is on CentOS 6, GNU sed version 4.2.1

The line that fails is exactly the same as above, just really long:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`factstvdus`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `caseinfo` AS select `files`.`fileNumber` AS `fileNumber`,`files`.`fileTitle` AS `fileTitle`,`files`.`openDate` AS `openDate`,`files`.`applicantID` AS `applicantID`,`files`.`adjusterID` AS `adjusterID`,`files`.`adjusterType` AS `adjusterType`,`files`.`employerID` AS `employerID`,`files`.`insurerID` AS `insurerID`,`files`.`TPAid` AS `TPAid`,`files`.`employerContact` AS `employerContact`,`files`.`insurerContact` AS `insurerContact`,`files`.`TPAcontact` AS `TPAcontact`,`files`.`claimNumber` AS `claimNumber`,`files`.`AAid` AS `AAid`,`files`.`AAfirmID` AS `AAfirmID`,`files`.`GLDAid` AS `GLDAid`,`files`.`coverages` AS `coverages`,`files`.`policyNumber` AS `policyNumber`,`files`.`policyLimits` AS `policyLimits`,`files`.`DOH` AS `DOH`,`files`.`courtLocationID` AS `courtLocationID`,`files`.`NORfiled` AS `NORfiled`,`files`.`baseRate` AS `baseRate`,`files`.`recommendations` AS `recommendations`,`files`.`GAICID` AS `GAICID`,`files`.`fileStatus` AS `fileStatus`,`files`.`lastEventDate` AS `lastEventDate`,`files`.`flatFee` AS `flatFee`,`adjusters`.`adjusterFirstName` AS `adjusterFirstName`,`adjusters`.`adjusterMiddleName` AS `adjusterMiddleName`,`adjusters`.`adjusterLastName` AS `adjusterLastName`,`adjusters`.`adjusterOfficePhone` AS `adjusterOfficePhone`,`adjusters`.`adjusterCellPhone` AS `adjusterCellPhone`,`adjusters`.`adjusterFax` AS `adjusterFax`,`adjusters`.`adjusterPhoneExtension` AS `adjusterPhoneExtension`,`adjusters`.`adjusterEmail` AS `adjusterEmail`,`ADJ`.`companyID` AS `clientID`,concat(if((`ADJ`.`companyID` < 1000),_utf8'0',_utf8''),if((`ADJ`.`companyID` < 100),_utf8'0',_utf8''),if((`ADJ`.`companyID` < 10),_utf8'0',_utf8''),`ADJ`.`companyID`,_utf8'-',`files`.`fileNumber`) AS `fullFileNumber`,`ADJ`.`companyName` AS `clientName`,`ADJ`.`companyNameShort` AS `clientNameShort`,`ADJ`.`officePhone` AS `clientOfficePhone`,`ADJ`.`tollFreePhone` AS `clientTollFreePhone`,`EMP`.`companyName` AS `employerName`,`INSUR`.`companyName` AS `insurerName`,`TPA`.`companyName` AS `TPAname`,`AA`.`lawyerFirstName` AS `AAfirstName`,`AA`.`lawyerMiddleName` AS `AAmiddleName`,`AA`.`lawyerLastName` AS `AAlastName`,`AA`.`lawyerReceptionist` AS `AAreceptionist`,`AA`.`lawyerNotes` AS `AAnotes`,`AA`.`lawyerOfficePhone` AS `AAofficePhone`,`AA`.`lawyerCellPhone` AS `AAcellPhone`,`AA`.`lawyerFax` AS `AAfax`,`AA`.`lawyerEmail` AS `AAemail`,`AAF`.`officePhone` AS `AAfirmOfficePhone`,`AAF`.`tollFreePhone` AS `AAfirmTollFreePhone`,`AAF`.`faxNumber` AS `AAfirmFax`,`AAF`.`EAMSno` AS `AAfirmEAMSno`,`AAF`.`EAMSname` AS `AAfirmEAMSname`,`AA`.`lawyerPhoneExtension` AS `AAphoneExtension`,`AAF`.`firmName` AS `AAfirmName`,`GLDA`.`lawyerFirstName` AS `GLDAfirstName`,`GLDA`.`lawyerMiddleName` AS `GLDAmiddleName`,`GLDA`.`lawyerLastName` AS `GLDAlastName`,`GLDA`.`lawyerOfficePhone` AS `GLDAofficePhone`,`GLDA`.`lawyerCellPhone` AS `GLDAcellPhone`,`GLDA`.`lawyerFax` AS `GLDAfax`,`GLDA`.`lawyerEmail` AS `GLDAemail`,`GLDA`.`userID` AS `GLDAUserID`,`applicants`.`applicantFirstName` AS `applicantFirstName`,`applicants`.`applicantMiddleName` AS `applicantMiddleName`,`applicants`.`applicantLastName` AS `applicantLastName`,`applicants`.`applicantDOB` AS `applicantDOB`,`applicants`.`applicantSSN` AS `applicantSSN`,`applicants`.`applicantJobTitle` AS `applicantJobTitle`,`applicants`.`homePhone` AS `applicantHomePhone`,`applicants`.`cellPhone` AS `applicantCellPhone`,`applicants`.`applicantEmail` AS `applicantEmail`,`APPPHYSLOC`.`locationID` AS `applicantPhysicalLocationID`,`APPPHYSLOC`.`locationAddress` AS `applicantPhysicalAddress`,`APPPHYSLOC`.`locationCity` AS `applicantPhysicalCity`,`APPPHYSLOC`.`locationState` AS `applicantPhysicalState`,`APPPHYSLOC`.`locationZipCode` AS `applicantPhysicalZip`,`APPMAILLOC`.`locationID` AS `applicantMailLocationID`,`APPMAILLOC`.`locationAddress` AS `applicantMailAddress`,`APPMAILLOC`.`locationCity` AS `applicantMailCity`,`APPMAILLOC`.`locationState` AS `applicantMailState`,`APPMAILLOC`.`locationZipCode` AS `applicantMailZip`,`AAPHYSLOC`.`locationID` AS `AAphysicalLocationID`,`AAPHYSLOC`.`locationAddress` AS `AAphysicalAddress`,`AAPHYSLOC`.`locationCity` AS `AAphysicalCity`,`AAPHYSLOC`.`locationState` AS `AAphysicalState`,`AAPHYSLOC`.`locationZipCode` AS `AAphysicalZip`,`AAMAILLOC`.`locationID` AS `AAmailLocationID`,`AAMAILLOC`.`locationAddress` AS `AAmailAddress`,`AAMAILLOC`.`locationCity` AS `AAmailCity`,`AAMAILLOC`.`locationState` AS `AAmailState`,`AAMAILLOC`.`locationZipCode` AS `AAmailZip`,`AAFPL`.`locationID` AS `AAfirmPhysicalLocationID`,`AAFPL`.`locationAddress` AS `AAfirmPhysicalAddress`,`AAFPL`.`locationCity` AS `AAfirmPhysicalCity`,`AAFPL`.`locationState` AS `AAfirmPhysicalState`,`AAFPL`.`locationZipCode` AS `AAfirmPhysicalZip`,`AAFML`.`locationID` AS `AAfirmMailLocationID`,`AAFML`.`locationAddress` AS `AAfirmMailAddress`,`AAFML`.`locationCity` AS `AAfirmMailCity`,`AAFML`.`locationState` AS `AAfirmMailState`,`AAFML`.`locationZipCode` AS `AAfirmMailZip`,`ADJPHYSLOC`.`locationID` AS `adjusterPhysicalLocationID`,`ADJPHYSLOC`.`locationAddress` AS `adjusterPhysicalAddress`,`ADJPHYSLOC`.`locationCity` AS `adjusterPhysicalCity`,`ADJPHYSLOC`.`locationState` AS `adjusterPhysicalState`,`ADJPHYSLOC`.`locationZipCode` AS `adjusterPhysicalZip`,`ADJMAILLOC`.`locationID` AS `adjusterMailLocationID`,`ADJMAILLOC`.`locationAddress` AS `adjusterMailAddress`,`ADJMAILLOC`.`locationCity` AS `adjusterMailCity`,`ADJMAILLOC`.`locationState` AS `adjusterMailState`,`ADJMAILLOC`.`locationZipCode` AS `adjusterMailZip`,`ADJBILLLOC`.`locationID` AS `adjusterBillLocationID`,`ADJBILLLOC`.`locationAddress` AS `adjusterBillAddress`,`ADJBILLLOC`.`locationCity` AS `adjusterBillCity`,`ADJBILLLOC`.`locationState` AS `adjusterBillState`,`ADJBILLLOC`.`locationZipCode` AS `adjusterBillZip`,`EMPPHYSLOC`.`locationID` AS `employerPhysicalLocationID`,`EMPPHYSLOC`.`locationAddress` AS `employerPhysicalAddress`,`EMPPHYSLOC`.`locationCity` AS `employerPhysicalCity`,`EMPPHYSLOC`.`locationState` AS `employerPhysicalState`,`EMPPHYSLOC`.`locationZipCode` AS `employerPhysicalZip`,`EMPMAILLOC`.`locationID` AS `employerMailLocationID`,`EMPMAILLOC`.`locationAddress` AS `employerMailAddress`,`EMPMAILLOC`.`locationCity` AS `employerMailCity`,`EMPMAILLOC`.`locationState` AS `employerMailState`,`EMPMAILLOC`.`locationZipCode` AS `employerMailZip`,`INSURPHYSLOC`.`locationID` AS `insurerPhysicalLocationID`,`INSURPHYSLOC`.`locationAddress` AS `insurerPhysicalAddress`,`INSURPHYSLOC`.`locationCity` AS `insurerPhysicalCity`,`INSURPHYSLOC`.`locationState` AS `insurerPhysicalState`,`INSURPHYSLOC`.`locationZipCode` AS `insurerPhysicalZip`,`INSURMAILLOC`.`locationID` AS `insurerMailLocationID`,`INSURMAILLOC`.`locationAddress` AS `insurerMailAddress`,`INSURMAILLOC`.`locationCity` AS `insurerMailCity`,`INSURMAILLOC`.`locationState` AS `insurerMailState`,`INSURMAILLOC`.`locationZipCode` AS `insurerMailZip`,`TPAPHYSLOC`.`locationID` AS `TPAphysicalLocationID`,`TPAPHYSLOC`.`locationAddress` AS `TPAphysicalAddress`,`TPAPHYSLOC`.`locationCity` AS `TPAphysicalCity`,`TPAPHYSLOC`.`locationState` AS `TPAphysicalState`,`TPAPHYSLOC`.`locationZipCode` AS `TPAphysicalZip`,`TPAMAILLOC`.`locationID` AS `TPAmailLocationID`,`TPAMAILLOC`.`locationAddress` AS `TPAmailAddress`,`TPAMAILLOC`.`locationCity` AS `TPAmailCity`,`TPAMAILLOC`.`locationState` AS `TPAmailState`,`TPAMAILLOC`.`locationZipCode` AS `TPAmailZip`,`EMP`.`officePhone` AS `employerOfficePhone`,`EMP`.`tollFreePhone` AS `employerTollFreePhone`,`EMP`.`faxNumber` AS `employerFax`,`INSUR`.`officePhone` AS `insurerOfficePhone`,`INSUR`.`tollFreePhone` AS `insurerTollFreePhone`,`INSUR`.`faxNumber` AS `insurerFax`,`TPA`.`officePhone` AS `TPAofficePhone`,`TPA`.`tollFreePhone` AS `TPAtollFreePhone`,`TPA`.`faxNumber` AS `TPAfax` from ((((((((((((((((((((((((`files` left join `adjusters` on((`files`.`adjusterID` = `adjusters`.`adjusterID`))) left join `applicants` on((`files`.`applicantID` = `applicants`.`applicantID`))) left join `locations` `APPPHYSLOC` on((`applicants`.`physicalLocationID` = `APPPHYSLOC`.`locationID`))) left join `locations` `APPMAILLOC` on((`applicants`.`mailingLocationID` = `APPMAILLOC`.`locationID`))) left join `locations` `ADJPHYSLOC` on((`adjusters`.`physicalLocationID` = `ADJPHYSLOC`.`locationID`))) left join `locations` `ADJMAILLOC` on((`adjusters`.`mailingLocationID` = `ADJMAILLOC`.`locationID`))) left join `locations` `ADJBILLLOC` on((`adjusters`.`billingLocationID` = `ADJBILLLOC`.`locationID`))) left join `companies` `EMP` on((`files`.`employerID` = `EMP`.`companyID`))) left join `companies` `INSUR` on((`files`.`insurerID` = `INSUR`.`companyID`))) left join `companies` `TPA` on((`files`.`TPAid` = `TPA`.`companyID`))) left join `lawyers` `AA` on((`files`.`AAid` = `AA`.`lawyerID`))) left join `lawyers` `GLDA` on((`files`.`GLDAid` = `GLDA`.`lawyerID`))) left join `companies` `ADJ` on((`ADJ`.`companyID` = `adjusters`.`adjusterCompanyID`))) left join `locations` `EMPPHYSLOC` on((`EMP`.`physicalLocationID` = `EMPPHYSLOC`.`locationID`))) left join `locations` `EMPMAILLOC` on((`EMP`.`mailingLocationID` = `EMPMAILLOC`.`locationID`))) left join `locations` `INSURPHYSLOC` on((`INSUR`.`physicalLocationID` = `INSURPHYSLOC`.`locationID`))) left join `locations` `INSURMAILLOC` on((`INSUR`.`mailingLocationID` = `INSURMAILLOC`.`locationID`))) left join `locations` `TPAPHYSLOC` on((`TPA`.`physicalLocationID` = `TPAPHYSLOC`.`locationID`))) left join `locations` `TPAMAILLOC` on((`TPA`.`mailingLocationID` = `TPAMAILLOC`.`locationID`))) left join `locations` `AAPHYSLOC` on((`AA`.`physicalLocationID` = `AAPHYSLOC`.`locationID`))) left join `locations` `AAMAILLOC` on((`AA`.`mailingLocationID` = `AAMAILLOC`.`locationID`))) left join `firms` `AAF` on((`files`.`AAfirmID` = `AAF`.`firmID`))) left join `locations` `AAFPL` on((`AAFPL`.`locationID` = `AAF`.`physicalLocationID`))) left join `locations` `AAFML` on((`AAFML`.`locationID` = `AAF`.`mailingLocationID`)));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me on both lines:

```
sed 's/DEFINER=`[a-z]*`@`localhost`//g' temp.sql
```

The only change was removing the escapes.  As a GNU `sed` extension, backslash-backtick matches the beginning of the pattern space.  (If the pattern space is a single line, this is the same as `^`.)  In this case, however, we needed to match an actual backtick.

Comment: Fantastic! That was my problem. Thanks!